# I can't change user's passwd on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, password

I want change 120 user's password. so I wrote `sudo echo 'user:passwd' | chpasswd`

but I had a message,

```
chpasswd: (user) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpaswd (line 1, user) password not changed
```

and also I tried another way using textfile, but I had same the message.

I can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The usual way to change the password is to use the [passwd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html) command.

If you want to use [chpasswd(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/chpasswd.8.html) or [usermod(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/usermod.8.html) you should carefully RTFM.

Be sure that the given password is compatible with the system configuration. And `sudo` should apply to the `chpasswd` command, so you probably want

```
echo 'user:passwd' | sudo chpasswd
```

In your case, `sudo echo 'user:passwd' | chpasswd`,
the `sudo` is applied only to `echo`, which is incorrect.

Comment: would even make more sense to run the whole thing as root instead of issuing `sudo` all the time.

Comment: @Fiximan: this really depends upon the system configuration. On some systems using `sudo`  would be very sensible.

Comment: Off: Using `sudo bash` _once_ might be even more sensible.

Comment: Or  `sudo -s` ....